# Upgrade to 22.10 not available

Tags: upgrade

I am following [this guide](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/upgrading-ubuntu-desktop) to upgrade my Ubuntu OS.

My system is up to date, and at 22.04 so I expect to be able to upgrade to 22.10 but I am not:

[image: software update dialog]

Also, my software update settings is set to
"Notify me for any new version."

[image: upgrade settings]

Yet, it does not.

How can I forcibly make my 22.04 upgrade to the 22.10 version?

Comment: Try [this](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/do-release-upgrade.8.html).

Comment: 22.10 is not yet released.  You won't get a 22.10 update notification until it's released.

Comment: The `-d` option (see @mikewhatever's link; ideally the *jammy* not *bionic* page but I believe it'd be identical)  will achieve it...  If you look at the QA (*Quality Assurance*) docs you'll see mention of it, as the `-d` option is what is used pre-release in QA to ensure the upgrade works.

Comment: @ThomasWard What about now? :)

Comment: @DidierL still not released yet.  Until the official release announcement goes off, it's not something we will support yet.  It also doesn't change the "Closed" state of this post.

Comment: @ThomasWard [announcement from earlier today](https://ubuntu.com/blog/canonical-releases-ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu), [official download page with 22.10 proposed](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop). Close reason does not seem to be valid anymore. (I know it takes time for everyone to get the upgrade pop-up, I’m just wondering if there would be a way to trigger it without the `-d` option)

Comment: @DidierL the problem is, this issue happened *only* during the time that this was not released.  Because it was unique to an 'in development release' **at the time of posting** the post was offtopic.  It remains offtopic because at the time of its posting, 22.10 was not released.  If OP has this problem still (they may need to wait a few days even for the command line to work as the popup and `do-release-upgrade` both use the core functionality and the same dataset to ID if upgrades are available), they can post a new post about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of this post, there's an obvious reason that you can't upgrade to 22.10: **22.10 is not yet released**.  You won't get a 22.10 update notification or an upgrade path from 22.04 to 22.10 directly until it's released.

You can upgrade to 22.10 while it's in development, but you **will lose all support from Ask Ubuntu while it's in development**.  I would wait until 22.10 is actually released before you attempt to upgrade to it.